# Preserving references when deserializing from json

Tags: java, gson

I am implementing a tagging system in my application. I have a main list of all `Tags` to tag objects with. Objects can have multiple tags, which are references to tags in the main list.

When I save my data to a file as json and then load it when my app runs again, these references are lost (`tagInMainList == referenceToTag` does not hold).

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if this were doable with JSON without a specific interner or something.  (Certainly I don't think Gson will have a built-in solution.)  You'd probably be better off avoiding the issue in the first place, either by avoiding JSON or by avoiding the need for reference equality to be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you loosely coupled your references, such that they only held a key value used in a map lookup?  You could still support an equality like `tagInMainList.equals(keyBasedReferenceToTag)` or `tagInMainList.getKey().equals(keyBasedReferenceToTag)`.  The JSON would be simpler and probably even more concise.

Answer (score 1):

I would care much about identity, unless you need to minimize memory usage and/or other heavy optimizations. I'm afraid, you need a custom deserializer. With it you can simply replace `return tag` by `return myTagInterner.intern(tag)` using Guava's [interner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html).

Comment: @maartinus: I care about identity because if I do `foo.changeSomething()`, and `bar` should be a reference to it but isn't, it won't be updated.